# Clojure deep-merge to ignore nil values

Tags: clojure, merge, null

I'm trying to deep-merge multiple maps in Clojure. I found many solutions online, most of which look something like:

```
(defn deep-merge
  [& xs]
 (if (every? map? xs)
   (apply merge-with deep-merge xs)
  (last xs)))
```

The problem with this solution is that if one of the maps is nil, it will delete all the previous maps (so if the last map is nil, the whole function will return nil). This is not the case in the regular merge function, which ignores nil values.
Is there any other easy implementation of deep-merge that ignores nil values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this at: https://github.com/circleci/frontend/blob/04701bd314731b6e2a75c40085d13471b696c939/src-cljs/frontend/utils.cljs. It does exactly what it should.

```
(defn deep-merge* [& maps]
  (let [f (fn [old new]
             (if (and (map? old) (map? new))
                 (merge-with deep-merge* old new)
                 new))]
    (if (every? map? maps)
      (apply merge-with f maps)
     (last maps))))

(defn deep-merge [& maps]
  (let [maps (filter identity maps)]
    (assert (every? map? maps))
   (apply merge-with deep-merge* maps)))
```

Thank you CircleCi people!

Comment: For posterity this seems to be a variation on what was originally in `clojure.contrib` and never received a maintainer and thus never made it into `clojure.core`. The issue and a link to the original code can be found here: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1468

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `nil`s at once?

```
(defn deep-merge [& xs]
  (let [xs (remove nil? xs)]
    (if (every? map? xs)
      (apply merge-with deep-merge xs)
      (last xs))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't provide the same behavior as merge. In the case of a 'nil' value, merge takes that value into account, but your implementation doesn't. For example: (merge {:a 3} {:a nil}) => {:a nil} , but (deep-merge {:a 3} {:a nil}) => {:a 3}

Comment: @Asher I think the question needs clarifying. It states that the regular merge function *ignores nil values*. You now say that *merge takes that value into account*. And the question asks for an *easy implementation of deep-merge that ignores nil values*, not for *the same behaviour as merge*. An example or two might help. I accept, of course, that this solution is not what you were looking for.

Comment: I will explain the difference: If one of the **maps** being merged is nil, then merge ignores it. But, if one of the **values** within a map is nil, the merge doesn't ignore it. Example for case 1: (merge {:a 1} nil {:b 2}) => {:a 1 :b 2}. Example for case 2: (merge {:a 1} {:a nil} {:b 2}) => {:a nil :b 2}